# Using grep to extract substring and append to front of line

Tags: grep

Given a `.txt` document with a number of lines, how would I extract a part of this line and append this extracted bit to the front of the line, I extract it from?

Example:

```
sometext("txt_to_be_ext", some_more_text)
```

Into:

```
"txt_to_be_ext",sometext("txt_to_be_ext", some_more_text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gawk`'s `match` function:

```
awk '{match($0,/.*("[^"]+").*/,a);$0=a[1]"," $0}1' input_file
"txt_to_be_ext",sometext("txt_to_be_ext", some_more_text)
```

Comment: What if I had two `""` elements in the string I'm matching on? This method gives me the last one, and changing `a[1]` to `a[0]` appends `some_more_text` to the front. Example I'm talking about: `sometext("txt_to_be_ext", some_more_text, "test")` would put `test` in the front, but what if I want to get to `txt_to_be_ext`?

Comment: add expected output with sample input

Comment: Input: `sometext("txt_to_be_ext", some_more_text, "test")`

Expected output: `"txt_to_be_ext",sometext("txt_to_be_ext", some_more_text, "test")`

Comment: use `awk '{match($0,/.*("[^"]+"),*/,a);$0=a[1]","$0}1'`

Comment: I'm an idiot and did a typo in the expected output. I've updated my comment, sorry.

Comment: `awk '{match($0,/^.*\(("[^"]+"),*/,a);$0=a[1]","$0}1'`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/sometext.*(\(".*"\).*/\1,&/' input_file
```

Brief explanation,

- Embraced `"txt_to_be_ext"` by parentheses, where `\1` would refer to the correspond matching.
- `&` would refer to the matched part for `sometext.*(\(".*"\).*`